# Empty array not appearing in $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have some checkboxes with the same name, and any of them can be checked.
The user can also check none.

I'm using the array notation:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="data[list][]" /> 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="data[list][]" /> 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="data[list][]" /> 3</li>
</ul>
```

But inside $_POST I'm only getting the array if at least one of them is checked.
I'm not getting an empty array if none of them are checked. This confuses my PHP form handler which is supposed to be abstract. I don't want to code ifs for certain field names in it :s

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value){

  $some_object->set($key, $value); 
  // value should be empty array if nothing is checked :s

}
```

Is there a way to just get the empty array?

Comment: What about codes? Html form and php posts? Show them to us please.

Comment: btw we are waiting for @Dagon

Comment: ok i added some codes but i dont see how it is relevant

Comment: sorry i was in the shower, what did i miss?

Comment: empty checkboxes are never returned, its a html thing (mostly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a purely html approach:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[list]" value="">
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="data[list][]" /> 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="data[list][]" /> 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="data[list][]" /> 3</li>
</ul>
```

This would always return at least:

```
"data" => array:1 [▼
   "list" => ""
]
```

List would be an empty string if no checkboxes are ticked and not an empty array, dont know if thats good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to just get the empty array?

No. If no checkbox is checked, the browser just does not send anything.

However I can understand you want to prevent ifs. You can do so by initializing to a default value. The [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) can be useful for that:

```
$_POST += ['data' => []];
```